# Using gulp to install jquery & bootstrap4 returns undefined property error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, npm, gulp, npm-install

I am trying to build a wordpress site with bootstrap 4 as a dependency using **npm** and **gulp** but cant seem to figure out why I keep getting this error when trying to run gulp:

```
$$$1.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = transitionEndEmulator;
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined
```

I installed **`jquery`**, **`popper`** and **`bootstrap`** using gulp and have added the following lines to my **gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var jquery = require('jquery');
var popperjs = require('popper.js');
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', './sass/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
});

gulp.task('js', function(){
    return gulp.src(['node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js', 'node_modules\popper.js\dist\popper.min.js', 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', './js/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./js/*.js', ['js']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'js', 'watch']);
```

---

What am I doing wrong so far?

Comment: Try using popper.js from `dist\umd` instead of `dist`.

Comment: @Klooven Tried it just now and still got the same error. Thanks for the suggestion anyway Klooven.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap 4 and popper are you using?

Comment: @Klooven Bootstrap v4.1.0 & Popper v1.14.3